# In laravel i'm getting the following error while add data to db

Tags: php, sql, laravel

i'm trying to add the category in dB by using following code but it shows an error like "SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'mydb.categories' doesn't exist (SQL: insert into `categories` (`category_name`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Fashion, 2018-03-13 09:44:38, 2018-03-13 09:44:38))"

my codes are as follows

Admin Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Category;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AdminController extends Controller
{
    public function show()
    {
       return view('admin/admin');

      // echo "here";
    }

    public function addCategory()
    {
        $category=new Category;
        $category->category_name = Input::get('category');

        $category->save();
        dd("2");

        //return view('admin');
    }

}
```

Admin.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .bod{
            background-color:#f8f8f8;
            border-shadow: 5px 10px 20px white inset;
            border-width:5px;
            margin-top:-12px;
        }
        .h1{
            font-family:"Book Antiqua";
            font-size: 90px;
            color: red;
            text-align: center;
        }
        div {
            border-radius: 5px;
            /*background-color: #f2f2f2;*/
            /*background-color: #7CA8C1  ;*/
            padding: 20px;
            position: relative;
            /*border:2px solid white;*/
            height: 200px;
            width: 50%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body class="bod">
<h1 class="h1">Admin</h1>
<div align="left">
    <form action="{{ route('addCategory') }}" method="get">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <label for="category" style="font-family: 'Book Antiqua';font-size: 48px">Category</label> <br/>
        <input type="text" name="category" id="category" placeholder="Enter the Category" style="width: 25%;height:35px; border:2px solid floralwhite">
        <input type="submit" name="add" id="add" value="ADD">
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

routing

```
Route::get('/addCategory','Admin\AdminController@addCategory')->name('addCategory');
```

Category model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    //

    protected $fillable = [
        'category_name',
    ];

}
```

db Strcture

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.7.4
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1:3306
-- Generation Time: Mar 13, 2018 at 10:12 AM
-- Server version: 5.7.19
-- PHP Version: 5.6.31

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Database: `mydb`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `category`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `category`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `category` (
  `category_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `category_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`category_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: Category model code please.

Comment: Have you migrated the database migrations.

Comment: kidly check now

Comment: have u migreated?

Comment: Have you created the database?

Comment: yes i have done that

Comment: can u add the migration file.

Comment: When u are storing the data the form method should be post 
and u need post route for the same.

Comment: what do you mean by migratinon file?

Comment: i did like u said earlier but itshows an error as follows "MethodNotAllowedHttpException
No message"

Comment: had u added the route did u give different route name also ?

Comment: how did u create the database table ? migration file or created directly using mysql or phpmyadmin ?

Comment: also can u show ur database structure.

Comment: check question i have edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your model

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Category extends Model
{
    //
    protected $table = "category";
    protected $fillable = [
        'category_name',
    ];
}
```

your table name is category and laravel thinks its categories you should use db migrations to create database tables which will help you stay away from this errors.

Comment: in model where i need to add?

Comment: happy it helped :)

Answer (score -1):

You have to mention a table name in model.

```
protected $table = "Categories";
```

Comment: Laravel will infer the table name from the class name, and it would follow the conventions, using `categories`. As you can see from the error, it's already getting the table name. This solves nothing.

Comment: this would work if categories was the db table.
but here the db table is different so we need to check that first. good try though